# Линейный список. Поиск

Tags: c, список

Помогите исправить код пожалуйста.

Программа правильно работает,но после вывода на экран нужного элемента просто зависает.

```
void find()
{
    car *p, *temp;
    char sp[10];
    clrscr();
    printf("Vvedite model' mashini,kotoruiu hotite naiti: ");
    scanf("%s", &sp);
    p = head;
    while (p == NULL)
    {
        if(strcmp((p->model), sp) == 0)
        {
            printf("[Marka]\t[Model]\t[Cvet]\t[Strana]\t[Cena]\n");
            printf("%s", p->marka);
            printf("\t%s\t", p->model);
            printf("%s\t", p->cvet);
            printf("%s", p->strana);
            printf("\t\t%s\n", p->cena);
            p = p->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Пользуюсь Borland C 3.1,пишу на Си. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Вы переходите к следующему элементу в цикле только если `strcmp` вернёт 0. Поэтому цикл после найдееного элемента топчется на месте.  30 секунд в отладчике сэкономили бы вам 5 минут на регистрацию и формулировку вопроса.

Comment: Думаю в `while (p==NULL)` нужно вместо `==` написать `!=` (или просто `while (p) { ...` или тоже стереотипно `for (; p; p = p->next) { ...`

Comment: нужно поменять `if` на `while`?

Comment: я поменял `p==NULL` на `p!=NULL`,просто забыл тут поменять. Проблема та же..

Comment: помогите пожалуйста,я так и не понял,что нужно сделать

Comment: Конечно нет. Если в списке м.б. только одна запись с заданной моделью (или хотите вывести только первую), то  `for (p = head; p; p = p->next) if (strcmp(p->model, sp) { printf(...); break; }`, а если несколько, то просто выбросьте `break`.

Comment: Нужно подумать головой. У нас тут не Хогвартс, «какое заклинание сказать, чтобы всё стало правильно» не прокатит. И воспользуйтесь наконец отладчиком, у Borland C++ 3.1 прекрасный отладчик, насколько я помню.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23227/discussion-on-question-by-adlo---).

Answer (score 3):

Вы переходите к следующему элементу в цикле только если strcmp вернёт 0. Поэтому цикл после найденного элемента топчется на месте. 30 секунд в отладчике сэкономили бы вам 5 минут на регистрацию и формулировку вопроса.